# Is it possible to display html content inside a jquery chosen plugin option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Is it possible to add any html element just like `<p><strong>` or any other inside a chosen select option?

```
var chzn = $('#chzn');
chzn.chosen({width:'125'});

//
chzn
    .append($('<option>', {
        value: 1,
        text : 'title: <strong> description </strong>'
    }))


chzn
    .val('')
    .trigger("chosen:updated")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xs3wQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
html : 'title: <strong> description </strong>'
```

Comment: This only works for lists built in JavaScript.  We need a way to pull HTML from option tags generated server-side.  Since option tags are not allowed to have HTML content, we'd have to embed HTML content in data-* attributes of the option tag and have chosen read them when it constructs the list.  I'm not sure if supports such a feature.

Comment: This `html` option is not documented and doesn't seems to work.

Comment: No, this doesn't work at all. Not for a select or for the chosen plug in.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
var $strongOptions = chzn.parent().find("li.search-choice span:contains('<strong>')");

$strongOptions.each(function () {
                var content = $(this).text();
                $(this).html($.parseHTML(content));
            });
```

Comment: this is the right idea, but you need it on all the options and the single selected item, and you need to do it whenever something changes or the dropdown is opened.